# Oracle forms Fsal full screen / borderless possible?

Tags: java, jvm, oracle12c, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

As the title indicates, can the fsal jar launch a form full screen? In 11g / internet explorer, simply launching ie full screen made this possible. Can the same be had with fsal browserless launcher? If it cannot be done with any built in command line arguments, are there any os or jvm level options to remove the border and title bar?

Answer (score 0):

In Forms 12, you can set the parent window to a maximized state at anytime during the session.  In your case, it sounds like what you want is to do it at startup (e.g. WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE, PRE-LOGON, etc).

```
SET_WINDOW_PROPERTY(FORMS_MDI_WINDOW, WINDOW_STATE, MAXIMIZE);
```

If you are running 12.2.1.4, you have some new applet parameters that can also be used with FSAL which might be of interest to you if you want to simulate something close to kiosk mode.

isResizable=false
alwaysOnTop=true

Hopefully what each does should be obvious.  If not, refer to the documentation for details.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/developer-tools/forms/12.2.1.4/working-forms/web-configuration-parameters.html

A more "kiosk"-style mode is planned for a future release.

Are you aware that you can ask your Oracle Forms questions directly to Oracle employees and other Forms users?  Check out the Oracle Forms Forum for the latest information about Forms.

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/forms